# Phonegap add plugin fails (errno 34) */plugin.xml

Tags: plugins, cordova, addition

When I add a plugin to a 3.0.0 phonegap project with an android platform, I have an error eventhough a bunch of files for the plugin are added. In addition to that error when I add it, the Android manifest never gets updated with the right authorizations.

```
$ cordova plugin ls

No plugins added. 'Use cordova plugin add <plugin>'.

$ sudo cordova plugin add "http://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-media-capture.git"

{ [Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/tmp/plugman-tmp1375200648427/*/plugin.xml']

  errno: 34,

  code: 'ENOENT',

  path: '/tmp/plugman-tmp1375200648427/*/plugin.xml',

  syscall: 'open' }

$ cordova plugin ls

[ 'org.apache.cordova.core.media-capture' ]
```

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem with the Connection plugin. Once I changed from "cordova plugin add" to "phonegap local plugin add", it worked fine.

```
$ phonegap local plugin add http://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-media-capture.git
```

Comment: Did you mean that you changed it from "cordova plugin add" to "phonegap local plugin add"?

Comment: @Fernando do you mind responding?  Your answer literally made no sense

Comment: He meant that he has used the phonegap version of CLI instead of cordova CLI.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, after some debugging and testing I finally solved the problem:

1. Open
   `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\plugman\src\util\plugins.js`.
2. Find `var cmd = util.format('git clone "%s" "%s"', plugin_git_url,
   path.basename(tmp_dir));` (line 42 ATM)
3. Replace it with `var cmd = util.format('git clone "%s"
   "%s"', plugin_git_url, tmp_dir);`.

This will make `git clone` clone to the absolute tmp path instead of the relative.

Comment: This was useful, I realized that initially when I installed cordova I had seen a warning: `npm WARN engine plugman@0.7.9: wanted: {"node":">=0.9.9"} (current: {"node":"v0.8.22","npm":"1.2.14"})` and since then I had upgraded to the latest version of node but hadn't rerun the `sudo npm install -g cordova` command. Re-running that command (because this post made me suspicious of plugman) tweaked or fixed whatever it needed to and let me go on!

Answer (score 1):

I received a similar error.  I resolved the issue by removing the media-capture plugin, installing the file plugin, then reinstalling the media-capture plugin

```
cordova plugin rm  org.apache.cordova.media-capture
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.media-capture
```

Maybe media-capture is dependent on the file plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same error :

Suppose if you want to add camera plugin then instead of giving:

**cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera**

use

**phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-camera**

and then it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

It turns out i had something really strange with my proxy. Possibly some data compression on the fly which made the data corrupt. Tethering from the phone solved the issue, after completely uninstalling cordova.