# Phonegap - can't add plugin using CLI

Tags: cordova, cordova-cli

When trying to add a plugin, I get the following error:

```
   phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org
    /repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git
    [phonegap] adding the plugin: https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-pl
    ugin-device.git

    fs.js:427
      return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                     ^
    Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\DOCUME~1\k\USTAWI~1\Temp\plugma
    n-tmp1379488251610\plugin.xml'
        at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:427:18)
        at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:284:15)
        at Object.module.exports.parseElementtreeSync (C:\Documents and Settings\k\Dane aplikacji\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\pl
    ugman\src\util\xml-helpers.js:107:27)
        at C:\Documents and Settings\k\Dane aplikacji\npm\node_modules\phonegap\
    node_modules\cordova\node_modules\plugman\src\util\plugins.js:67:39
        at C:\Documents and Settings\k\Dane aplikacji\npm\node_modules\phonegap\
    node_modules\cordova\node_modules\shelljs\shell.js:1707:7
        at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:641:7)
        at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
        at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:5)
```

I tried to solve that problem using advice from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952332/phonegap-add-plugin-fails-errno-34-plugin-xml) , but it does not change anything.

Will be really grateful for any suggestions how to solve that issue.

Comment: What version of phonegap cli are you using?

Comment: 3.0.0-0.14.3 -> that's what "phonegap --version" prints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody had similar problem with PhoneGap on Windows - installing the latest Git version solves all the problems...